# Do I need sepearate distribution certificate and development certificate for each of my app?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, xcode8.2, iosdeployment

I have searched for this question and what I have got from most searches is  that:
**We can only have 3 "distribution certificates at most" and it is a good practice to use ONLY ONE distribution certificate for all the apps**.

However what about the **development certificates**?
Can I also just use one for all the apps? or do I need individual "development Certificates" for each app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's standard practice to just use one `distribution certificate` for all the apps.
For development you can use separate `Development Certificates`.

Development certificates are based on bundle identifiers. Its best practice to use different development certificate for different apps. Still, if you have same bundle id of different apps, you can use same certificate as well.

Comment: u mean for development certificate i have to create new ones each time for a new app?

Comment: ohh so that means the max number of  "distribution certificates" are only 3 and for "development certificates" i can create as many as i want to associate them with new apps right? because right now in my keychain i have one distribution cert and one development cert. was just wondering i should create one more development cert for this new app. i should not use the old development cert for this new app right?

Comment: No for development certificates with one account you can make 100. As with one apple account only 100 apps can be uploaded

Comment: ohh ic ic thats clear now! no wonder when i let xcode "automatically assign development team" it choses the previous app's development certificate and build always fails and says " select development team" ! Thanks a lot @Arpit Jain

Comment: by the way @Arpit Jain i just created another development certificate but it created the exact same string within the bracket("RTXXXXX") which looks exactly the same as the other development cert. why is that so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144827/discussion-between-arpit-jain-and-mikethetechy).